# xcodebuild Unsigned IPA Notification not send to users in the case genrate xarchive Unsigned?

Tags: ios, swift

When send ipa direct notificaton send to client successfuly , another case when generate unsigned xarchive & extract ipa as enterprise tp upload ipa on app center for example notification not send.

and this is command line to genrate unsigned xarchive :-

```
xcodebuild -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme schemename -configuration release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/app.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=”” CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My Problem after generating an unsigned archive and export ipa file , notification not send to client